# how can I send a file using form data with an array of items?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the form type:

```js
export interface FormProps {
  typeForm: string
  voltage: number
  current: number
  material: string
  phaseNumber: number
  powerDistributionCompany: PowerDistributionCompanyFormProps
  file: File | null
}
```

and I need to send this form in multipart/form-data. But if I use a FormData class and define my form in a new var of this class, the item array is sent in a format that the api doesn't understand

```js
const file = data.file && data.file

const formData = new FormData()
file && formData.append('dwg', String(file))

voltage && formData.append('TENSAO', String(voltage))
projectName && formData.append('ORC_NOME', projectName)
projectId && formData.append('PRJ_ID', projectId)
items && formData.append('ITPS', JSON.stringify(items))

await apiForm
  .post(`${typeForm}`, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
```

the array is sent as ITPS: [object Object],[object Object] and the api returns the error: Unexpected token 'o', "[objectObje"... is not valid JSON.

I try to post this:

```
const file = data.file && data.file

const formData = new FormData()
file && formData.append('dwg', String(file))

voltage && formData.append('TENSAO', String(voltage))
projectName && formData.append('ORC_NOME', projectName)
projectId && formData.append('PRJ_ID', projectId)
items && formData.append('ITPS', JSON.stringify(items))

await apiForm
  .post(`${typeForm}`, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
```

And I hope the API returns successfully.

Comment: have you tested your API with a working multipart/form-data before, using Postman or alike? Just to be sure your endpoint actually allows it

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your API is accepting only JSON data, you can change the API Request Params to accept Multipart or if you really need to send this data in same way.

You could try using https://square.github.io/okhttp library to create Multipart file data and convert it and send append it into Form data or the alternative will be converting your file to base64 and append it into Form data .